# C# Object Hierachy Design

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have created a series of related objects in my C# application...

Object A contains a list made up of Object B's, Object B's contain a list of Object C's.

Object A is currently writing information to a log file, depending on Object A's instance name (e.g. there are three Object A instances in my application "Server 1", "Server 2", "Server 3").  So each instance of Object A writes to it's own log file.

How do I get Object B to write information to the "Server 1" log file if it is in a collection belonging to "Server 1"?

As far as I know, Object B does not know it is part of a collection of Object B's belonging to Object A.  Object B knows nothing about Object A and hence can't get Object A's name to write to the same log file for the particular instance of Object B.

Have I designed this poorly?  Is there a method or way for Object B to check if it is part of some collection at runtime and get information from Object A?

Comment: You could always add an Object A type field/property to record what object B's parent is. Not sure how great that is though...

Comment: Either B needs a reference to A (as Parent/Owner) or A must poll B for logging. Or create a Logger instance/interface that A passes to all its B's.

Answer (score 0):

In the end as suggested I was able to pass in the parents name to the child and use this when logging.